# Unable to retrieve data of type Paint.Cap from a bundle

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bundles

I have looked everywhere for this and I couldn't find any answer.

I am sending data over an intent like this.

```
MainActivity.java

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("key",Paint.Cap.SQUARE);
            startActivity(intent);
```

My issue is in retrieving it, I don't know which get method to use and I couldn't find any source online that tells me.

```
SecondActivity.java

Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();

    if(extras !=null)
    {
        if(extras.containsKey("key"))
        {
            Paint.Cap shape = //which method to use here?

        }
    }
```

If it's something so silly please tell me, I am still a beginner and tried my best to find it on my own.

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between Activities in Android application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that `Paint.Cap` is an `enum` and so it implements the interface `Serializable`.

This means that you called the version of `putExtra` that takes a `Serializable`.

To get it out again you can do

```
Paint.Cap shape = (Paint.Cap) extras.getSerializable("key");
```